# Generic Inquiry with Actions

Tags: acumatica

If I have a simple generic inquiry e.g. list of customers or inventory items on certain conditions. Is it possible to add a button or menu and execute an action on selected records ? And by action, I mean nothing grand. Just update certain fields on selected customers or items.

Thanks

Comment: I think its easier to write customized screen for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for...  [GI Mass Actions](http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/09/mass-processing-using-gi.html)

You can setup the entry point for your GI, enable Mass Actions, define the Mass Action, then you should be able to use it from the Action menu option.